# Bash - OpenSSL decryption returns "bad magic number" error after file has been converted from hex

Tags: linux, bash, openssl, binary, hex

I have a file in hex format that I am trying to decrypt using OpenSSL. However, after converting the file from hex back to binary, and after typing in the correct password, I receive a `bad magic number` error. I'm using bash on Debian Linux.

I've tried to reproduce the error with a simple file and here's the steps I've taken:

1. Write text to file: `nano test.txt` and write `hello world`
2. Encrypt file with OpenSSL: `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -in test.txt -out test.data` with password `1234`
3. Delete original file: `rm test.txt`
4. Decrypt `test.data` with OpenSSL: `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -in test.data -out test.txt` with password `1234`
5. Confirm that the above works as expected (no problems here)
6. Convert `test.data` to hex: `cat test.data | hexdump -C | tee test.hex`

   (This is how my original file was converted, so this is the format my data is in now)
7. Convert `test.hex` back to binary: `xxd -r -p test.hex test.data.copy`
8. Try to decrypt `test.data.copy`: `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -in test.data.copy -out test.txt` with password `1234`. Here I receive the `bad magic number` error and see that the decrypted file is blank

Edit: Thanks to @Barmar, I do see that the files are different from each other. So it looks like the error was in using `cat` to output the binary. Knowing this, is there any way to still recover the original file?

Where did I go wrong here? Were there some extra bytes inserted somewhere along the way that I'm not aware of? Since I only have the hex file and not the original, what should I do to make sure it gets properly decrypted? Thank you

Comment: Don't use `cat` to view binary files. There's probably some non-printing characters that differ. Compare `od -c test.data` and `od -c test.data.copy`.

Comment: What's the difference in the size of the files?

Comment: @Barmar Ah, I see, thanks for the tip. I see that the files are in fact different. So knowing that the original file was converted to hex using `cat` and not through `od`, is there any way to properly recover that data?

Comment: @lonelonetraveller The problem isn't `cat`, it's `hexdump -C` vs `xxd -r -p`. Specifically, `xxd -r -p` expects a *plain* hex dump (with no addresses, or anything else -- just raw hex), but `hexdump -C` includes an address at the beginning of each line, *and* an ASCII-ish representation at the end of each line. `xxd -r -p` will treat the addresses and any de-hex-able part of the ASCII as part of the data, and therefore include a lot of garbage in the resulting file. You need to strip off everything other than the plain hex before feeding it to `xxd -r -p`.

Comment: Use `xxd` to create the original hex dump, and it should be able to revert it.

Comment: @Barmar I'll give it a shot and see how it goes. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GordonDavisson for showing me that the problem was with using `hexdump -C`.

As he mentioned in his comment, using `hexdump -C` adds a bunch of extra data to the file which `xxd -r -p` will include in the resulting output file.

I simply removed the line numbers at the beginning of each line and the ASCII representation at the end. I then removed new lines and double whitespaces to get a plain hex file. After getting plain hex, I was able to convert to binary using the same `xxd -r -p` command and successfully decrypt using `openssl`.

Thanks for all the help, I would never have figured it out otherwise